# Validation using ValidationRules - Ok button should trigger validation and not continue execution

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have a simple example application, 2 text boxes a validation rule and a button.
I want my button to trigger validation and if it's not valid, not to continue with its execution.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="FirstName">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MyValidationRule ErrorMessage="Enter first name" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="LastName">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MyValidationRule ErrorMessage="Enter last name" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Content="Ok" />
```

The validation rule:

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string valueToCheck = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueToCheck))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

My OkCommand is empty method:

```
  OkCommand= new RelayCommand(OkRequested);

  private void OkRequested()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

However, no matter if the text boxes are empty `OkCommand` gets executed properly. What am I doing wrong here? I want text boxes to be styled if they're not valid (I've excluded styles from example), but that does not happen.

Comment: what does your model look like?

Answer (score 1):

You should add into `OkCommand` something like this. And same for other textBoxes.

```
if ( Validation.GetHasError( textBox1 ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show( Validation.GetErrors( textBox1 )[0].ErrorContent.ToString() );
    return;
}
```